# SQL - Trying to find customer by their shopping channel

Tags: sql, oracle, churn

Hello I am trying to find the customers who just shop online and just shop in store and the customers who shop both online and in store. So when I add them up they should be equal to my total customers.

I am trying to find the new and returning customer by their shopping channel. I need a sql to give me all the new customer and returning customers who have shopped in store, and then in a separate table all the new/returning customers who have shopped only online and then people who have shopped both online and in store (crossover customers). So that when I add off them together they should be equal to my total customers in each category (new and returning).
It should look like below:

[how data should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBa8g.png)

I have created a sample database as well. I am also trying to break the customer by new and returning customers and later by their age range.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96a7b85c8ca0da7f7c40f20205964d9b

these are some of the queries which I have tried: Below is the one which shows me the new and the returning customers who have only bough online:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(is_new, 1, 'New Customers', 'Returning Customers') type_of_customer,
    COUNT(distinct individual_id) count_of_customers,
    SUM(count_of_transactions) count_of_transactions,
    SUM(sum_of_quantity) sum_of_quantity
FROM (
    SELECT
    individual_id,
    SUM(dollar_value_us),
    sum(quantity) sum_of_quantity,
    count(distinct transaction_number) count_of_transactions,
    CASE WHEN MIN(txn_date) = min_txn_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.individual_id, 
        a.dollar_value_us,
        a.txn_date,
        a.quantity,
        a.transaction_number,
        b.gender,
        b.age,
        MIN(a.txn_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.individual_id) min_txn_date,
        A.TRANTYPE

    FROM transaction_detail_mv   a
    join gender_details b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id
    WHERE 
        a.brand_org_code = 'BRAND'
        AND a.is_merch = 1
        AND a.currency_code = 'USD'
        AND a.line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S'
        AND a.individual_id not in (select individual_id from transaction_detail_mv where trantype = 'POS' )

)
WHERE 
    txn_date >= TO_DATE('10-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
    AND txn_date < TO_DATE('17-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
GROUP BY
    individual_id,
    min_txn_date
    )
GROUP BY is_new
```

and to find the new and returnign customers who buy form POS is bewow:

```
SELECT
        DECODE(is_new, 1, 'New Customers', 'Returning Customers') type_of_customer,
        COUNT(distinct individual_id) count_of_customers,
        SUM(count_of_transactions) count_of_transactions,
        SUM(sum_of_quantity) sum_of_quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT
        individual_id,
        SUM(dollar_value_us),
        sum(quantity) sum_of_quantity,
        count(distinct transaction_number) count_of_transactions,
        CASE WHEN MIN(txn_date) = min_txn_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.individual_id, 
            a.dollar_value_us,
            a.txn_date,
            a.quantity,
            a.transaction_number,
            b.gender,
            b.age,
            MIN(a.txn_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.individual_id) min_txn_date,
            A.TRANTYPE

        FROM transaction_detail_mv   a
        join gender_details b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id
        WHERE 
            a.brand_org_code = 'BRAND'
            AND a.is_merch = 1
            AND a.currency_code = 'USD'
            AND a.line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S'
            AND a.individual_id not in (select individual_id from transaction_detail_mv where trantype = 'ONLINE' )

    )
    WHERE 
        txn_date >= TO_DATE('10-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
        AND txn_date < TO_DATE('17-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    GROUP BY
        individual_id,
        min_txn_date
        )
    GROUP BY is_new
```

I am trying to find new and old customers who have shopped both online and in POS. Please HELP !

Comment: Thank you for making a db fiddle. Can you please edit your post to more clearly explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish, and please post your attempts ?

Comment: @JerryM. I am trying to find the new and returning customer by their shopping channel. I need a sql to give me all the new customer and returning customers who have shopped in store, and then in a separate table all the new/returning customers who have shopped only online and then people who have shopped both online and in store (crossover customers). So that when I add off them together they should be equal to my total customers in each category (new and returning)

Comment: @JerryM. Hello I updated the queries which I am using. appreciate you rhelp !!

Comment: I don't understand your desired output table. What is Age Range? What is "Female" vs Female Count? What is taxation count?.

I think this question should be closed and reopened with a bit more direction. Though we appreciate your attempts here, it looks like there are MULTIPLE requests (3 queries), each with different requirements, and it is not clear what errors you are getting and how they are different from what you are expecting.

Comment: @JerryM. I am trying to find the new vs returning customers and then i have segmented them by their age range and their gender. I already have the queries for that which I have attched in this post. now i am trying to segment it by their shopping channel. To see who has bought in store only, online only and both online and instore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this:

```
SELECT
        DECODE(is_new, 1, 'New Customers', 'Returning Customers') type_of_customer,
        COUNT(distinct individual_id) count_of_customers,
        SUM(count_of_transactions) count_of_transactions,
        SUM(sum_of_quantity) sum_of_quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT
        individual_id,
        SUM(dollar_value_us),
        sum(quantity) sum_of_quantity,
        count(distinct transaction_number) count_of_transactions,
        CASE WHEN MIN(txn_date) = min_txn_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.individual_id, 
            a.dollar_value_us,
            a.txn_date,
            a.quantity,
            a.transaction_number,
            b.gender,
            b.age,
            MIN(a.txn_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.individual_id) min_txn_date,
            A.TRANTYPE

        FROM transaction_detail_mv   a
        join gender_details b on a.individual_id = b.individual_id
        WHERE 
            a.brand_org_code = 'BRAND'
            AND a.is_merch = 1
            AND a.currency_code = 'USD'
            AND a.line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S'
            AND a.individual_id not in (select individual_id from transaction_detail_mv where ((trantype = 'ONLINE') OR (trantype = 'POS') )

    )
    WHERE 
        txn_date >= TO_DATE('10-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
        AND txn_date < TO_DATE('17-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    GROUP BY
        individual_id,
        min_txn_date
        )
    GROUP BY is_new
```

Comment: Iit gives me the totals I just need to find out who is shopping in POS only , online only and then customers who shop both

Comment: Are you looking for 3 separate queries then?

Comment: Yes I am looking for 3 different queries you can change the query if you want to if you think that the present one will not show the correct results